# Weird Normals Issue

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So I tried applying the normal map on this Zenith 10mm from Deus Ex, I simply went on the textures tab and loaded up the normal map after which I edited the UV so everything fits.
This is what happens on one side:
[image: The creates a black-static sort of thing]

while the other side is completely normal:
[image: Normal side]

What am I doing wrong? BTW I am a beginner in blender so sorry in advance if this is something majorly stupid.

Comment: Upload your file to blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com, so others can  take a look. Use the "pack textures"option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I found the mistake:
[image: Fixed!]
I forgot to check the "Normal Map" box under Image Sampling in the textures tab.